# How can I change the moving objects speed at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The manager script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class DronesManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject target;
    public float movementSpeed;
    public float launchTime;

    public Transform dronesUnchild;

    private List<GameObject> drones = new List<GameObject>();
    private float currentDroneSpeed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        currentDroneSpeed = movementSpeed;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("Base");

        drones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Drone").ToList();

        StartCoroutine(MoveDrone());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(currentDroneSpeed != movementSpeed)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < drones.Count; i++)
            {
                var droneControl = drones[i].GetComponent<DroneControl>();

                droneControl.movingSpeed = movementSpeed;
            }

            currentDroneSpeed = movementSpeed;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveDrone()
    {
        // same as you did:
        drones = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Drone").ToList();

        foreach(var drone in drones)
        {
            drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>().target = target.transform;
        }

        while (drones.Count > 0)
        {
            // pick one at random, get it
            int index = Random.Range(0, drones.Count);
            var drone = drones[index];

            // remove it from list
            drones.RemoveAt(index);

            // TODO: might want to check/guard if drone == null ... this guards against it
            // being Destroy()ed and yet still lying around in our list marked as "dead"

            // simplified your get-component-and-go-if-not-already-going code here
            var droneControl = drone.GetComponent<DroneControl>();
            if (droneControl.go == false)
            {
                droneControl.movingSpeed = movementSpeed;
                droneControl.go = true;
                drone.transform.parent = dronesUnchild;
            }

            // wait
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(launchTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add this part in the Update

```
void Update()
    {
        if(currentDroneSpeed != movementSpeed)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < drones.Count; i++)
            {
                var droneControl = drones[i].GetComponent<DroneControl>();

                droneControl.movingSpeed = movementSpeed;
            }

            currentDroneSpeed = movementSpeed;
        }
    }
```

and this script is attached to each moving object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroneControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public float turnSpeed = .01f;

    Quaternion rotGoal;
    Vector3 direction;
    public float movingSpeed;
    public bool go = false;

    private bool waitBeforeRotate = false;
    private bool startRotating = false;

    #region AddedCode
    public float targetRange = 1.0f;

    private bool IsTargetReached(Vector3 dronePos, Vector3 targetPos)
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(dronePos, targetPos);
        return distance < targetRange;
    }
    #endregion AddedCode

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // next line is modified to incorporate the range check
        if (go && !IsTargetReached(transform.position, target.position))
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (waitBeforeRotate == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine(StartRotating());

                waitBeforeRotate = true;
            }

            if (startRotating)
            {
                direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
                rotGoal = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotGoal, turnSpeed);
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator StartRotating()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

        startRotating = true;
    }
}
```

but it's never change the speed of moving objects.

if the speed of each moving object in the editor start is 5 for example and in the manager script I change the speed to 100 the speed of each object is still 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is happening because after picking a random drone in IEnumerator you instantly remove it from the list?

So in Update() you set a speed for all drones, except the ones that are already moving.

Comment: I marked not to use the line that remove them from the list.  //drones.RemoveAt(index); so now changing the speed is working I just wonder why I removed it from the list at the first place ? what was the logic ? I mean is it fine to keep them in the list ?

Comment: I guess the original intention was to pick one drone from scene and "activate" it, then after delay (launchTime) "activate" another drone and so on and so forth, until all drones from list are "activated".

Comment: For example you could change the "drones" list to "stationaryDrones" and remove the drone as you did in coroutine after you activate it.
But also add another list "allDrones" and update drones movementSpeed from that list in Update().